# How to know which flavor of netcat I'm using?

Tags: linux, netcat

There are two flavors of `netcat`: *netcat-openbsd* and *netcat-traditional*.

How to know which flavor of netcat I'm using? I've tried `man nc` but it doesn't say what flavor it is.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, you can install multiple flavors in your machine. So the answer depends on how many flavors you've installed and what command you type.

`netcat-traditional` and `netcat-openbsd` is available to be install via package manager `apt` in Ubuntu. In my case I also build from source to install `GNU netcat` flavor via [this official website](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/download.php).

For "openbsd" flavor, you can figure out location binary name with `dpkg -L` <package-name> (Googling yourself to find equivalent of `dpkg L` if yor package manager is not `apt`):

```
$ dpkg -L netcat-openbsd | grep /bin
/bin
/bin/nc.openbsd
```

Then use `type -a` to confirm that binary name `nc.openbsd` is searchable in `$PATH` and interpreted as command:

```
$ type -a nc.openbsd
nc.openbsd is /bin/nc.openbsd
nc.openbsd is /bin/nc.openbsd
```

For "traditional" flavor is same:

```
$ dpkg -L netcat-traditional | grep /bin
/bin
/bin/nc.traditional
$ type -a nc.traditional
nc.traditional is /bin/nc.traditional
nc.traditional is /bin/nc.traditional
```

That's means I can issue command `nc.openbsd` to run `netcat-openbsd` tool, and also command `nc.traditional` to run `netcat-traditional` tool. (There may confuse where the command contains '.' but package name contains '-' )

Seems like there are 3 flavors to install via `apt`:

```
$ apt-cache search netcat --names-only
netcat-openbsd - TCP/IP swiss army knife
netcat - TCP/IP swiss army knife -- transitional package
netcat-traditional - TCP/IP swiss army knife
```

But actually `netcat` is dummy package only:

```
$ apt-cache show netcat | grep Description-en  -A 2
Description-en: TCP/IP swiss army knife -- transitional package
 This is a "dummy" package that depends on lenny's default version of
 netcat, to ease upgrades. It may be safely removed.
```

So you can only install `netcat-openbsd` and `netcat-traditional` via `apt` if you want:

```
sudo apt-get install netcat-openbsd
sudo apt-get install netcat-traditional
```

How about commands `nc` and `netcat` ? They can tied to multiple flavors searchable by `$PATH`, one of the path will run if you type `nc` or `netcat`. Again, you can use `type -a` to check, whereas priority is the first line (as **bold** below):

```
$ type -a nc 
nc is /usr/local/bin/nc
nc is /bin/nc
nc is /usr/local/bin/nc
nc is /bin/nc
$ type -a netcat
netcat is /usr/local/bin/netcat
netcat is /bin/netcat
netcat is /usr/local/bin/netcat
netcat is /bin/netcat
```

You can use `realpath` to figure out resolved path of them:

```
$ realpath /usr/local/bin/netcat 
/usr/local/bin/netcat
$ realpath /bin/netcat 
/bin/nc.openbsd
$ realpath /usr/local/bin/nc
/usr/local/bin/netcat
$ realpath /bin/nc
/bin/nc.openbsd
```

4 of them only 2 paths is unique in my system, one is "GNU", and the other one is "openbsd":

```
$ /usr/local/bin/netcat --version | head -1
netcat (The GNU Netcat) 0.7.1
$ /bin/nc.openbsd -h |& head -1
OpenBSD netcat (Debian patchlevel 1.130-3)
```

That's means if I type `nc` OR `netcat`, it will execute `/usr/local/bin/netcat` which is "GNU Netcat".

You can try `update-alternatives` to adjust the resolved symlink path:

```
$ realpath /bin/nc
/bin/nc.openbsd
$ realpath /bin/netcat
/bin/nc.openbsd
$ sudo update-alternatives --config nc
There are 2 choices for the alternative nc (providing /bin/nc).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /bin/nc.openbsd       50        auto mode
* 1            /bin/nc.openbsd       50        manual mode
  2            /bin/nc.traditional   10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /bin/nc.traditional to provide /bin/nc (nc) in manual mode
$ realpath /bin/nc
/bin/nc.traditional
$ realpath /bin/netcat
/bin/nc.traditional
```

It changed both `/bin/nc` and `/bin/netcat` resolved symlink¹ to `/bin/nc.traditional`, but still it doesn't changed the flavor if I type `nc` OR `netcat` since `/usr/local/bin/` still has higher precedence over `/bin` in my `$PATH`:

```
$ /bin/nc -h |& head -1
[v1.10-41]
$ nc -h |& head -1
GNU netcat 0.7.1, a rewrite of the famous networking tool.
$ type -a nc | head -1
nc is /usr/local/bin/nc
```

Note that there are more flavors of netcat, e.g. [ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/), [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/), [sbd](https://tools.kali.org/maintaining-access/sbd), [netcat6](http://www.deepspace6.net/projects/netcat6.html), [pnetcat](http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/pnetcat.html), and [cryptcat](http://cryptcat.sourceforge.net/).

¹ <sub>The actual symlink updated were `/etc/alternatives/nc` and `/etc/alternatives/netcat`, which `/bin/nc` and `/bin/netcat` were already symlink to `/etc/alternatives/nc` and `/etc/alternatives/netcat` respectively.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

When I run `nc --version`, I get:

```
netcat (The GNU Netcat) 0.7.1
Copyright (C) 2002 - 2003  Giovanni Giacobbi

This program comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
You may redistribute copies of this program under the terms of
the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.

Original idea and design by Avian Research <hobbit@avian.org>,
Written by Giovanni Giacobbi <giovanni@giacobbi.net>.
```

Maybe the BSD version will say specifically as well.

Comment: Referencing another answer, what do you get for `nc -h`?

Comment: `GNU netcat 0.7.1, a rewrite of the famous networking tool.`  followed by the help text.

Comment: That's interesting. It seems that `nc -h` works in "both" versions, whereas `nc --version` works only for the GNU implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac (though it presents itself as the GNU version):

```
$ nc -h
GNU netcat 0.7.1, a rewrite of the famous networking tool.
[ further output snipped ]
```

On a Linux box (specifically Ubuntu):

```
$ nc -h
[v1.10-41]
[ further output snipped ]
```

`netcat --version`, suggested in another answer, threw an 'invalid option' error to `--version`, so `-h` seems to potentially be a universal test.

Comment: Does GNU netcat comes pre-installed with mac OS or did you install it yourself?

Comment: I honestly do not recall, but the fact that it's in `/usr/local/bin` rather than `/usr/bin` implies I may have installed it with `brew`.

Comment: One last question if you don't mind, is the binary for GNU netcat called "netcat" and "nc" is just a link for "netcat"? (because I see here that the binary is called "netcat": https://fedora.pkgs.org/25/rpm-sphere/netcat-gnu-0.7.1-15.2.x86_64.rpm.html).

Comment: On my system, `nc` is just a symlink to `netcat`. You can check yourself with `file $(which nc)` which gives me `/usr/bin/nc: symbolic link to netcat`.